# Two children with the same key mongodb _id

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose, redux-toolkit

i got  this error : 
 **Encountered two children with the same key, `610bebf8b6f3820b38b0c613`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version** 

but i use mongodb id so no way 2 id be them same
it happen when i load more items...
im using redux toolkit express mongoose

it happen sometimes not always

**flatList :**

```
<View style={{flex: 1, margin: 10, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      <Search />
      {users.pending && !users.users.length ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      ) : users.users.length === 0 ? (
        <Text>No users</Text>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={users.users}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Card user={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

**usersSlice :**

```
 getUsersSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.pending = false;
      if (state.users.length === 0) {
        state.users = action.payload;
      } else {
        state.users = [...state.users, ...action.payload];
      }
      state.skip = state.users.length;
    },
```

**apiCall**

```
export const getUsers = async (dispatch, skip) => {
  dispatch(getUsersStart());
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://10.0.2.2:5000/users?skip=${skip}`);
    dispatch(getUsersSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getUsersError());
    console.error('error => ', error.message);
  }
};
```

**server :**

```
export const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  const skip =
    req.query.skip && /^\d+$/.test(req.query.skip) ? Number(req.query.skip) : 0;
  console.log(' req.qury.skip >>>>', req.query.skip);
  try {
    const users = await User.find({}, undefined, { skip, limit: 7 });
    users.map((user) => {
      user.name = decryptString(user.name, process.env.CRYPTO_PASSWORD);
    });
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).json('Server Error');
  }
};
```

i get 
**virtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.**

i think about delete duplicate item but i think not good choice

Answer (score 0):

> but i use mongodb id so no way 2 id be them same it happen when i load more items

your assumption can be wrong in multiple ways. Mongo IDs are unique in the database, but you could be getting duplicate values because of a variety of reasons.

I suspect that the API is giving you overlapping data and you merge new data with the old data without checking -

```js
state.users = [...state.users, ...action.payload];
```

modify this to have a basic uniqueness check - and only add elements that are not already in the old list

Comment: i did this[ ...new Map(arr.map(item => [item._id, item])).values(),];state.users = uniqueObjects;
it work ... but is it good for performance ?? if we deal with a lot of object !!
is there any way to solve it without maping and remove duplicate object

Comment: but is it good for performance? it depends. Since this only runs when new items are loaded - it probably is ok. Remember not to prematurely optimise stuff. If performance is bad - you can edit this piece of logic when the need arrives.